# Energy Consumption of AC Motors with same capacity and same hp

Tags: power, motor, energy, units

I have 2 3-phase motors with same capacity of 45kW, hp 60,rated Voltage is 415V, VFD 55kW connected separately to a Vessel Line that is used to  mixing of few components.i.e, it looks like this. (I can say that these two motors are identical)

```
Vessel 1 --> motor1
vessel 2 --> motor2
```

When loaded with same size (Load size), Motor 1 consumes high unit `10kWh` for a shift (runs for 35 mins) and motor 2 consumes low energy `6kWh` (runs for 35 mins). In some cases, for same load size it is vice-versa, motor 2 consumes 7kWh and motor 1 consumes 4kWh.

Any explanation why this happens or any other factor affecting the Energy Consumption of these Motors?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a few more measurements, as your assumptions (same motor type, same load magnitude, and the implicit same run duration) are not borne out by your observations.

Before it's worth swapping the motors, you need to get to the point where your observations are *repeatable*. **In some cases, for same load size it is vice-versa, motor 2 consumes 7kWh and motor 1 consumes 4kWh.** If by this you do really mean that the relative motor consumption varies by a factor of 2 without explanation, then you don't have a hope of doing controlled experiments with your present assumptions.

A few things to try. Are the ingredients in one line aerated or more diluted, and so easier to move? What about temperature? Are the source and delivery hoppers sometimes at different fill levels? Does one line stop and start without you noticing? You know your plant better than we do, crank up your imagination. Is there another load on the consumption meter that sometimes draws power? Start guessing what factors could affect it, start measuring them, and see if you can find a reason for the apparently unexplained variability.

Comment: Does one have long compared to short periods of running ie the number of starts?

Answer (score 0):

Power consumed is related to the load on the motor, not the motor. Flow = energy in a pump, so less flow = less energy. If the energy values are different, there is something different about the load. Either viscosity is different, or if that is the same, there might be some sort of flow restrictive device in the pipe somewhere and that is restricting flow.